# Getting an error while making histogram vith ggplot: Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent)

Tags: r, histogram

Hi I am trying to create a histogram via ggplot:

[prtcrn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrcHY.png)

```
retail2$Time <- as.factor(retail2$Time)

a %>% ggplot(aes(x=Time)) + geom_histogram(stat="count",fill="indianred")

Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'a' not found
```

Anyone could help me to correct it?

Comment: Well firstly you have two `+ +` in a row

Comment: The object `a` should be a `data.frame`.  I do not see it defined as such in either your code here or in the screenshot from R Studio.  perhaps your `data.frame` is what you have labelled `retail2` in your screenshot?